# set -u only inside included script

Tags: bash

I have a rather extensive collection of bash scripts that are included in other scripts to execute functions in them. I would like to use `set -u` within my included scripts without that propagating outside my scripts, e.g. to any including scripts. Do I need to set this in every single function inside my script or can I set it in the file "globally"?

As per comment: I use the scripts as follows:

```
source magic/helper/script.sh

foo
```

Contents of `script.sh`:

```
function foo
{
  # ...
}
```

Comment: How are you invoking the included scripts? Do add an example to make us understand the problem better

Comment: The problem here is source takes the env variables/options from the parent shell invoked from. So you are left with an option to enable the `-u` option in the parent shell invoking the source

Comment: Yeah, i know, that's why I'm asking

Answer (score 0):

Any option enabled by `set -` can be disabled by `set +` thus you could do something like:

```
set -u
source magic/helper/script.sh
set +u

foo
```

You can also call `set -u` and `set +u` inside the included file.

Comment: That's very true, but unset variables inside the functions inside the magic/helper/script.sh won't be detected until the function is actually called, so this doesn't help.

Comment: @arne if I understand correctly, you don’t mind if `set -u` it set before or after sourcing the included script, what matters is that the `-u` option is enabled when its functions are invoked?

Comment: Exactly. And if at all possible, not by adding set -u/set +u to each function.

Comment: Then I don’t know how to to it, I don’t even know if this makes sense. The quick'n'dirty way would be to automatize the option with something like `source <(sed -e 's/{/{set -u;/g' -e 's/}/set +u;}/g' magic/helper/script.sh)` assuming that curly braces are used exclusively for beginning and ending your functions.